# Access Hive Metastore server information from Hive Shell

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, derby

I know it is possible to have a metastore located on a remote server.  In order to set this up, I must specify the ConnectionURL, Driver, Username, and Password in the hive-site.xml file.  Is it possible to access the information in the hive-site.xml file from the hive shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `SET` command through the Hive CLI. But it prints all the variables in the namespaces `hivevar, hiveconf, system, and env.` So, you could use it with `grep` to print just the properties you need. For example if you want to see what is the value of `mapred.reduce.tasks` which you set in hive-site.xml then you could do this :

```
bin/hive -S -e "set" | grep mapred.reduce.tasks
```

Or to get the metastore related info you could do this :

```
bin/hive -S -e "set" | grep metastore
```

I don't know if this what you were expecting, but it does the trick for me. Hope this helps you too.